# Efficient Converting DataTable to List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serialization, datatable

I want to serialize the DataTable to a List in C#. My code is taking around 10 minutes for 100K data to fetch and convert to a list. Previously tried with sequential way but it three times more time to process. So, I tried Parallel and it saved 1/3 of time. But, still, it's too slow.

If anyone can help to make it fast. Any help is appreciated.

```
public async Task<List<DataPointModel>> GetDetails(HashParameterModel parameterModel)
{
    List<DataPointModel> result = new List<DataPointModel>();
    try
    {
        var query = "USP_GetDetailsFromMetaData";
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupID", parameterModel.GroupID);
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                sqlConnection.Open();
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter
                {
                    SelectCommand = sqlCommand
                };
                da.Fill(dataSet);

                dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
                DataTable dataTable1 = dataSet.Tables[1];
                var questionList = dataTable1.AsEnumerable();
                if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(dataTable.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, row =>
                    {
                        DataPointModel model = new DataPointModel();
                        model.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]);
                        model.GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(row["GroupID"]);
                        model.ProviderID = Convert.ToInt32(row["SalvageProviderID"]);
                        model.ClaimNumber = row["ClaimNumber"].ToString();
                        model.PolicyNumber = row["PolicyNumber"].ToString();
                        model.DataPoint1 = row["DataPoint1"].ToString();
                        model.DataPoint2 = row["DataPoint2"].ToString();
                        model.DataPoint3 = row["DataPoint3"].ToString();
                        model.DataPoint4 = row["DataPoint4"].ToString();
                        model.FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                        model.LastName = row["LastName"].ToString();
                        model.PrimaryDamage = row["PrimaryDamage"].ToString();
                        model.Type = row["TypeCode"].ToString();
                        model.LossDate = row["LossDate"].ToString();
                        model.QuestionList = (from p in questionList
                                              where p.Field<int>("ID") == model.ID
                                              select new QuestionResponseModel()
                                              {
                                                  QuestionID = p.Field<int>("QuestionID").ToString(),
                                                  Response = p.Field<string>("ResponseValue")
                                              }).ToList();
                        result.Add(model);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The DataSet has two DataTable

```
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0]; // Details
DataTable dataTable1 = dataSet.Tables[1]; // QUestionList
```

I think the time is consumed when its looping interlly for QuestionList, which may have around 120K rows. Any Suggestions

Comment: Skip the DataTable and create your objects directly from the DataReader.

Comment: Or use dapper to materialize your list directly from the query result

Comment: Don't read 120K datarows into memory.

Comment: What will you do with this data in the end?

Comment: Check if the stored procedure really only queries the fields you need and map them directly into your model. Does fetching the data from the database use more time then filling the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and quick to implement performance improvment would be to build a look up table from your `questionList`, and access this to fetch the question instead of doing this piece of code

```
model.QuestionList = (from p in questionList
                      where p.Field<int>("ID") == model.ID
                      select new QuestionResponseModel()
                      {
                          QuestionID = p.Field<int>("QuestionID").ToString(),
                          Response = p.Field<string>("ResponseValue")
                      }).ToList();
```

So add the following

```
var questionList = dataTable1.AsEnumerable();
//maybe add .AsParallel() - questionList.AsParallel().ToLookUp(...)
var questionLookUp = questionList.ToLookUp(x => x.Field<int>("ID"), x => new QuestionResponseModel() { QuestionID = x.Field<int>("QuestionID"), Response = p.Field<string>("ResponseValue") });
```

And than use it like this

```
model.QuestionList = questionLookUp[model.ID].ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup

Code is untested, hope I didn't make to many errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are there duplicate model IDs in the Details table? If so this could help to avoid running the question list query multiple times:

```
                        model.QuestionList = getQuestions(model.ID);
```

Method:

```
    public Dictionary<int, List<QuestionResponseModel>> questionBuffer = new Dictionary<int, List<QuestionResponseModel>>();

    public List<QuestionResponseModel> getQuestions(int ID)
    {
        if (questionBuffer.ContainsKey(ID)) return questionBuffer[ID];

        List<QuestionResponseModel> questions =  (from p in questionList
                              where p.Field<int>("ID") == model.ID
                              select new QuestionResponseModel()
                              {
                                  QuestionID = p.Field<int>("QuestionID").ToString(),
                                  Response = p.Field<string>("ResponseValue")
                              }).ToList();
        questionBuffer.Add(ID, questions);
        return questions;
    }
```

Comment: So a look-up table with extra steps :)

Comment: Ha, i guess. Your post wasnt there when i started typing. But if  the details table only had a small number of model ids this would avoid pulling the whole 120k rows into memory

Comment: They are already in memory, inside the datatable. Your solution has the draw-back of enumerating `questionList` multiple times, for each unique `ID`. It only gives a perfomance increase if `ID` get passed multiple times, since you are caching the result for each `ID`, though judging from the name `ID` it would be suprising this to be the case, and `ID` should be unique. The `ToLookUp` only enumerates the list once and builds the look up as it goes. Sure building the lookup once takes some time, but it should perform better than enumerating a 120k multiple times.